How does ColorRamp Constant work and why is it different in my case as in tutorial?
I'm following this tutorial but I'm wondering why the configuration of my ColorRamp node is different. In the video it's way to the left.

But in my case it's on the right and I'm not able to scroll it past half to the left as in the video:

Also the shadow disappears when scrolling the ColorRamp past 50% to the left. Why is that? Can someone explain how exactly this Constant ColorRamp works and why is my setup different from theirs?

Shadow disappears past 50% to the left but in video those settings are all on the left.

Here's my setup on Blender 4.2.3


Your world is much brighter than the one in the tutorial. The world illuminates even the shadow areas where the light does not reach the object. And if the world illuminates the object beyond a certain point - for example, the shadow has a brightness value of 0.5 or higher, then moving the slider below this brightness value will turn everything in the shade to this color.
Here the shader with all sliders below 0.5 and your world with a Strength of 1, everything gets the color of the right slider at 0.3, since all parts of the object are brighter than that:

Now nothing changed in the Color Ramp, but I set the world's Strength to a much lower value of 0.1:

Of course it is not necessarily the Strength or at least not alone, you have a light blue as the color. The darker the color, the higher the Strength can be before it affects your shader undesirably. As you can see in your screenshots from the tutorial, the environment looks darker than yours.

@MeganLove To get crisp shadows in EEVEE in Blender 4.2, make sure to set the Sampling > Shadows > Resolution in the Render Properties to the max value of 1 and in the Light Properties decrease the Resolution Limit to the lowest value of 0.0001 m: shadow settings 4.2

Thanks for the response! I found out I also had to set the Radius & Filter to zero in addition to setting the Resolution Limit to 0 for it to be super crisp.

@MeganLove Well, a higher radius of course makes a softer shadow, but that is true for new EEVEE, old EEVEE and also Cycles... so I thought that was clear since you just asked for the difference between the new version you're using and the older one which the tutorial used. Large light sources make soft shadows, small light sources make sharper shadows. That's physics and it has always been like that.
